# Compare measured time difference with float

Tags: c++, time, compare, measure

I have some code, where I want to measure a time difference in c++. After a certain time, saved in a float variable, I want to start some stuff.
Is there a way to cast a time duration to float or to compare with a float value?

Here's some code:

```
float maxDiff = 5;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//do something
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;
if(elapsed>=maxDiff
{//do something else}
```

Comment: Perhaps all you need is [a `std::chrono::duration` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)?

Comment: And for future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't actually see anything wrong in the code-sample. Would be good to explain what is or isn't happening, and how that is different from what you expect.

Comment: Have you tried defining the "elapsed" varialbe as std::chrono::duration<float> instead of std::chrono::duration<double>?

Answer (score 1):

the following code works:

```
float maxDiff = 5;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//do something
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<float> elapsed = finish - start;
if (elapsed.count() > maxDiff)
{
}
```

Note that you might want to use `std::chrono::steady_clock` as `high_resolution_clock` may not be stable (you can check by calling `is_steady`) and `steady_clock` is usually high enough resolution for most purposes and will prevent problems with changes in the system clock.